# Solutions to a polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The polynomial
$$P(x)=x^{173}-5x^{157}+\ldots+4x+12$$
has coefficients that are whole numbers. The number $a$ **cannot** be a solution to the equation $P(x)=0$, independent of coefficients in the ‘hidden’ part for

(A) $a=2$

(B) $a=-3$

(C) $a=5$

(D) None of A-C

It is clear that
$$\prod_{i=1}^{173} (-\alpha_i)=12$$
and
$$-\sum_{i=1}^{173} \alpha_i=-5$$
but then what? Anyone that can help? TIA.

Comment: This is not that clear... Why cannot I put some constant into the hidden part to make any of those values of $a$ be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's C.

Here's why.  $P(5) = 5^{173} - 5 \cdot 5^{157} + \dotsb + 4 \cdot 5 + 12$, where all terms except $12$ are multiples of $5$, whereas $12$ isn't, so the sum cannot be $0$, which is another multiple of $5$.

$2$ and $-3$ both divide $12$, so they cannot be ruled out in this manner.

Comment: What do you think about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155780/solutions-to-a-polynomial-equation#comment8605268_4155780)

Comment: @VIVID I assume that the ellipsis is supposed to contain terms from $x^2$ to $x^{156}$ only, so that like terms are already merged.  I see there is room for exploitation :)

Comment: A little justification about how A,B are excluded, notice that $p(2)$ is divisible by $4$ and $p(-3)$ by $9$, so we can easily adjust/add the term in $x^2$ to make $2$ and $-3$ roots.